# Cannot drag and drop widgets in admin

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently helping someone with their Wordpress site. They are running Wordpress 3.5.1. The problem is that I cannot drag and drop any widgets into their widget areas. I ran the Javascript console and found this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hoverIntent'
load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=admin-bar,hoverIntent,common,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery…:3
```

I have moved the whole Wordpress site to a testing server. The problem is that this Wordpress site is running a custom theme, and a bunch of plugins (even som custom as well), so I guess updating the WordPress-script is not an option, if I don't want to mess up things completely.

I have deactivated and removed both the theme and all plugins, and the problem still persists. I can't understand why, as it should technically be a clean WordPress install.

Any suggestions would be appreciated though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I was missing some necessarry JS files in the wp-includes/js/ folder. Downloaded files from http://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/.

Answer (score 0):

Try deactivating plugins one by one and check to see if everything is ok. I has happened alot that plugins break javascript or css in the backend that cause some js functionalities to break.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I have already done that. Deactivated and renamed the plugins folder.

Comment: If the problem persists with wordpress default theme and no custom plugins active, maybe the core is modified by someone. You can either grab a clean wordpress 3.5.1 and replace the old core files or update the wordpress on ur test server